# Navigation between Blazor Winforms pages

Tags: winforms, blazor

After a successfull experience with Blazor web server and Maui hybrid with Blazor, I'm now taking my first steps integrating my Blazor components in Winforms.
But I found no tutorials with samples of how to navigate between different pages/windows/forms.
Html links do not seem to work, and neither do NavigationManager:

Default page, app successfully loads it:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<div>
    <button @onclick="OnClick">Go to page 2</button>
    <a href="#" @onclick="@OnClick" @onclick:preventDefault>go to page 2</a>
    <a href="page2" >go to page 2</a>
</div>
@code {
    private void OnClick()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Page2");
    }
}
```

Second page, no way to open it from previous one:

```
@page "/Page2"
<div>Wellcome to Page2</div>
```

Should I better navigate between Forms?

**Update 1**

I finally got it working having the component trigger an event on a form state class which instantiates a new form and shows it.

I guess I should better declare a singleton service with global appstate class in program.cs and hold all form instantiation from there, but I can't find the right way to declare it on a Blazor Winforms project.

My last version as follows, but appState is null when initializing Form1:

The singleton that communicates between Blazor compolnents and Winforms forms:

```
public class AppState
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? GotoForm;
    public void NavigateNext()
    {
        GotoForm?.Invoke(this,new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

The component which feeds content to each form:

```
@inject AppState appState

<h3>Welcome to Form @FormNumber</h3>

<button @onclick="appState.NavigateNext">Goto page @AltFormNumber()</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int FormNumber { get; set; }

    int? AltFormNumber()=>FormNumber == null ? null : 3-FormNumber;
}
```

The default form:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [Inject] AppState appState { get; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
            //services.AddSingleton<FormState>();

            blazorWebView1.HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";
            blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            //var appState = blazorWebView1.Services.GetRequiredService<AppState>();
            appState.GotoForm += NavigateNext;

            blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Pages.FormComponent>("#app", 
                new Dictionary<string, object?> { { "FormNumber", 1 } });
        }

        private void NavigateNext(object? sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
```

The alternative form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    [Inject] AppState appState { get; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
        //services.AddSingleton<FormState>();

        blazorWebView1.HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";
        blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        //var appState = blazorWebView1.Services.GetRequiredService<AppState>();
        appState.GotoForm += NavigateNext;

        blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Pages.FormComponent>("#app",
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { { "FormNumber", 2 } });
    }

    private void NavigateNext(object? sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

The Program.cs:

```
internal static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        ServiceProvider = host.Services;

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  What aren't you telling us?

Comment: My goal was to close and open windows the way traditional windows work. Job done, but I can't have the singleton appState working if I declare it on program.cs